# Updating Multiple Users ADGroup by EmployeeID

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-powershell, azure-ad-powershell-v2

I'm trying to update AzureADGroupMember for multiple users in a CSV File by Employee.

This is what I've got assisted with, but looking to have it update by UPN instead of EmployeeID. This was the successful code that updates ADGroupMember by UPN.

```
$users = Import-csv "C:\Temp\testgroup2.csv" 

$users | ForEach-Object{
Add-AzureADGroupMember -ObjectId 599992-xxxxxxxxxx-699999e9e - 
RefObjectId (Get-AzureADUser -ObjectId $_.UPN).ObjectId
}
```

This is the code where I changed UPN to update by EmployeeID in the CSV.

```
$users = Import-csv "C:\Temp\testgroup2.csv" 

$users | ForEach-Object{
Add-AzureADGroupMember -ObjectId 599992-xxxxxxx-6ee9999e - 
RefObjectId (Get-AzureADUser -ObjectId $_.EmployeeID).ObjectId
}
```

This is the error message I get when trying to update by EmployeeID.

```
Get-AzureADUser : Error occurred while executing GetUser Code: 
Request_ResourceNotFound Message: Resource '18616' does not exist or one 
of its queried reference- property objects are not present.
```

This is what I used to verify that the employee actually has an EmployeeID in Azure.

```
Get-AzureADUser -ObjectID Xxxxx@hxxxxxx.com | Select-Object *
```

Any idea why it's reading that the employeeID doesn't exist in Azure even though I've verified?

Thank you,

Update: Adding screenshot of my csv setup, I only have Employee ID in there:
[CSV Setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gRjeg.png)

Update 2: Screenshot of the script I'm running in powershell: [Script in PS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m2IL2.png)

Comment: I'm  thinking that updating with EmployeeID instead will be more of an  Set-AzureADUserExtension ?

Comment: Could it solve your issue?

Comment: this is the error message i got when running. I verified the ObjectID group was correct     Add-AzureADGroupMember : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'RefObjectId' because it is null.
At line:4 char:88 @JoyWang

Comment: i did add make adjustment by adding IF ($refobjectid) { and didn't get no error messages, but groups didn't update as they should;     If ($refobjectid) {
    Add-AzureADGroupMember -ObjectId 32xxc77f2-xxxxxx-sdfsdfxx -RefObjectId $refobjectid
}
} @JoyWang

Comment: First, make sure the user has the employeeId(not null, should be the same with the values in csv file). My script just works for the user has the employeeId, if some users don't have the employeeId, you will not be able to get the user objectid, so the `Add-AzureADGroupMember` will not work.

Comment: You could check if the employeeId of the user is null by `Get-AzureADUser -ObjectId xxxxxx | ConvertTo-Json`. In the `ExtensionProperty`, `employeeId` is there.

Comment: yeah, i verified with Get-AzureADUser -ObjectID xxxxxx@xxxxxx | Select-Object * and Get-AzureADUser -ObjectId xxxxxx | ConvertTo-Json and i see valid EmployeeID in both

Comment: Is the employeeId same with the one in your csv file? What is the format of your csv file? Could you try my sample csv file?

Comment: Yea, my CSV is setup like: EmployeeID
322
425
696
999999
888888 tried to add a screen shot, but couldn't

Comment: Please provide the screenshot of your csv file in your question, I will test for you tomorrow.

Comment: @JoyWang thank you, screenshot has been added at the bottom of the question.

Comment: Per my test, I am sure it will work. Did you try my complete script? Or try to update the `AzureAD` powershell module.

Comment: so i did see an upgrade and i went from 2.0.2.4 to 2.0.2.16. I was really hoping this was the fix, but after i ran the script i got the same error message. I'm copying the exact code from your post...only thing im editing is the location of the csv file and updating the GroupID that i want the user in after -ObjectID @JoyWang

Comment: I also attached a screenshot of the script I'm running in Powershell just so you can see what I'm seeing when running the script @JoyWang

Comment: updated powershell azuread module: Install-Module AzureADPreview -AllowClobber then tried script again and still getting 'Add-AzureADGroupMember : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'RefObjectId' because it is null.
At line:4 char:88' @JoyWang

Comment: Could you make sure every user has the `employeeId`? Anyway, the error points out that.

Comment: I ended up working with a coworker and this worked out with updating by employeeID: $users = Import-csv "C:\temp\test.csv" 
$_all_azure_ad_users = Get-AzureADUser -all $true

foreach($user in $users){
 
    $refobjectid = ($_all_azure_ad_users | Where-Object {$_.ExtensionProperty.employeeId -eq $user.EmployeeID})| select objectId

    Write-Host $refobjectid

    Add-AzureADGroupMember -ObjectId xxxxx-xxxxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxxxx -RefObjectId $refobjectid.ObjectId
}  thank you for your time and efforts! @JoyWang

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `employeeId` is not the same with `ObjectId`, so you could not pass employeeId 
 to the ObjectId property.

Try the script as below, it works fine on my side.

```
$users = Import-csv "C:\Users\joyw\Desktop\testgroup.csv" 
foreach($user in $users){
    $refobjectid = (Get-AzureADUser | Where-Object {$_.ExtensionProperty.employeeId -eq $user.employeeId}).ObjectId
    Add-AzureADGroupMember -ObjectId 9d42d3ea-xxxxxxxx-c31428b600ad -RefObjectId $refobjectid
}
```

My `.csv` file:

```
UPN,Role,employeeId
leeliu@xxxxxx.onmicrosoft.com,role1,12345
test@xxxxxx.onmicrosoft.com,role2,123
```

[image]